# startActivityForResult force closes my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanted to make two buttons on my main activity to `startActivityForResult`

Every time I press either of these buttons my app force closes , and I can't figure out why!

Here is the code of the two buttons :

```
public void billiards (View v)
{

    Intent billiards = new Intent(this,Billiards.class);

    startActivityForResult(billiards,99710);

}



public void snooker (View v)
{

    Intent snooker = new Intent(this,Snooker.class);

    startActivityForResult(snooker,99711);



}
```

Here is the code of `Billiards` activity :

```
public void bsave (View v)
{

    Double dbgames = Double.parseDouble(ebgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcbgames = (dbgames)*0.50;

    Double btotal = (calcbgames);


    Intent billiards=new Intent();
    billiards.putExtra("btot",String.valueOf(btotal));
    setResult(99710,billiards);
    finish();

}
```

Here is the code of `Snooker` Activity :

```
public void ssave (View v)
{

    Double dsgames = Double.parseDouble(esgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcsgames = (dsgames)*1.00;

    Double stotal = (calcsgames);


    Intent snooker=new Intent();
    snooker.putExtra("stot",String.valueOf(stotal));
    setResult(99710,snooker);
    finish();

}
```

And here is the code of `onActivityResult` in my `MainActivity` :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==99710) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String billiardstot = data.getStringExtra("btot");

            String bt = billiardstot;

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(BToatal, bt);

            editor.commit();


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Request Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode==99711) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String snookertot = data.getStringExtra("stot");

            String st = snookertot;

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(STotal, st);

            editor.commit();


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Result Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Whenever i press on `Billiards` or `Snooker` Buttons the app force closes

And here is the LogCat :

```
08-18 02:11:01.220 11972-11972/cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe, PID: 11972
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityEclair.checkForValidRequestCode(BaseFragmentActivityEclair.java:64)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:868)
                                                                             at cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe.ItemMenu.billiards(ItemMenu.java:149)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-18 02:11:03.043 11972-11972/cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11972 SIG: 9
```

Comment: "at cafe.al_sheikhabuhamzehcafe.ItemMenu.billiards(ItemMenu.java:149)" This means that the error is caused by something on line 149 in `ItemMenu.java`. What line is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode`

the values you are using for your `requestCode` are too large

stick to something less than ‭65535‬